# H-bridge made of MOSFETs

Tags: voltage, mosfet, h-bridge

If we have an H-bridge made of 4 N-MOSFETs, the gate voltage applied to each pair must be different because in an active circuit the sources will have different voltages. How much?

Comment: The difference will be approximately that of the value of the DC supply feeding the bridge.

Comment: For large supply voltages, grossly exceeding typical \$V_{GS}\$ of MOSFETs, high-side driver ICs take care that the high-side MOSFET gates are driven with respect to the local Source Voltage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>This assumes an on-off type H-bridge and not a linear H-bridge used in  bridge tied audio amplifiers.</sub>

> *How much?*

If you ignore protection features (required to limit gate-source voltages when the supply exceeds the maximum gate-source voltage), to efficiently drive current through the load requires these gate voltages to be present: -

[image]

And clearly, the difference in voltage between the two driven gates for the MOSFETs that are activated is just the supply voltage.